# Camunda BPM - migration from 7.14.0 to 7.18.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, camunda, bpmn

I'm trying to upgrade Camunda version in one of my current Spring Boot projects - from 7.14.0 to 7.18.0.

I've changed the versions of Camunda libs and from the application perspective everything works great, but I'm concidering If I should also make some changes in the database schema to avoid problems with past non-finished processes?

I've read camunda docs and found the latest patch: 'engine_7.14_patch_7.14.2_to_7.14.3.sql'
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/installation/database-schema/#liquibase-patch-level-update

https://jira.camunda.com/browse/CAM-12832

Does it mean that after version 17.4.3 db schema stays the same?

If not can someone provide me some tips where can I find any informations about the migrations steps?

Answer (score 0):

Pleas efollow

- https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/update/minor/714-to-715/
- https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/update/minor/715-to-716/
- https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/update/minor/716-to-717/
- https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/update/minor/717-to-718/

to get from 7.14 to 7.18.